# Caption from alt is not showing up with onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I have two JS-functions which I want to work together but I can't figure out how..

The first function is for showing the "alt" as caption below images.
The second function is an onClick function which shows the next image by clicking on the image.

My Problem is that when I activate the onClick function and the next image is shown, the "alt" caption doesn't change.

Here is the part of the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row my-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">

      <!--thumbnail container-->
      <div class="thumbnailContainer">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 ">
        <!--START MAIN CONTENT-->
        <div class="hideMobile">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"></span>
            <img class="img-fluid img-overlay" id="expandedImg" style="max-height: 80vh;" onClick="nextImage(this)" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12233047/pexels-photo-12233047.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-chandan-suman-12233047.jpg&fm=jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="container expandedImgSize d-flex justify-content-center" id="imgtext">
            <figcaption style="color: #999999; font-size: 12px;" class="figure-caption">CAPTION
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--END MAIN CONTENT-->

      </div>
      <!--col-md-9-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--END Wrapper-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Data
    const imagesArr = [{
        image: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/stack-of-books-picture-id157482029?b=1&k=20&m=157482029&s=170667a&w=0&h=EVs9M4nx2kPCdIBYMULaSfj75k-wqjEAsaE8GkLwkbw=',
        alt: '<br>Test<br>Test1<br>Test1',
      },
      {
        image: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-stack-of-papers-on-a-white-background-picture-id178580846?k=20&m=178580846&s=612x612&w=0&h=agODFyEclthiTCyRGMtKoYDGsXRD0GmVpvJnEPhSQws=',
        alt: '<br>Test<br>Test2<br>Test2',
      },
      {
        image: 'https://st2.depositphotos.com/2769299/7314/i/450/depositphotos_73146765-stock-photo-a-stack-of-books-on.jpg',
        alt: '<br>Test<br>Test3<br>Test3',
      },

    ];

    const createImage = (image, alt, index) => {
      return `<img src="${image}" alt="${alt}" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" onClick="expandingImage(this)" currentimage="${index}"/>`;
    };

    // Logic
    const createImages = (images) => {
      let final = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const e = images[i];
        final += createImage(e.image, e.alt, i);
      }
      return final;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      console.log('Loaded')

      const container = document.querySelector('.thumbnailContainer');

      container.innerHTML = createImages(imagesArr)
    });

    const nextImage = (img) => {
      const current = +img.getAttribute('currentimage');
      if (current < imagesArr.length - 1) {
        img.setAttribute('src', imagesArr[current + 1].image)
        img.setAttribute('currentimage', current + 1)
      }
    }

    function expandingImage(imgs) {
      const expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
      const imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
      expandImg.src = imgs.src;
      imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
      expandImg.setAttribute("currentimage", imgs.getAttribute('currentimage'))
      expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In nextImage you set the src attribute.  You could also set the alt attribute similarly.

Comment: hey, thanks for your quick response! I'm sorry but I'm still a code noob and do not know what i am exactly doing... can you maybe explain or write the specific part?

Comment: I tried 
img.setAttribute('alt', imagesArr[current + 1].image) 
but it didn't work

Comment: For starters, it doesn't work because you are pulling the wrong information. You are pulling the **image** value of your `imagesArr` array, not the **alt** value. So you would want to use `img.setAttribute('alt', imagesArr[current + 1].alt)` to set the **alt** attribute of the image. But that has nothing to do with the caption/text on the page. For that you would use `document.querySelector("#imgtext").innerHTML = imagesArr[current + 1].alt` as **imgtext** is the id of the element containing your caption/text.

Comment: I really have soo much to learn